# getWeb3ClientVersion() returns null

Tags: dapps, web3j, android

I'm trying to create an android Dapp by using the web3j library. I'm using connection to a local private Ethereum blockchain. When I'm trying to display the Client version it returns null.
This is the code:

```
 static public Web3j web3j = null;
 static String clientUrl = "http://192.168.1.33:8501"; 
 Web3ClientVersion client = new Web3ClientVersion();
 web3j = Web3jFactory.build(new HttpService(clientUrl));
       try {
        client = web3j.web3ClientVersion()
                 .sendAsync()
                 .get();

    }  catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 Log.e("client info: ", "Client version:  " + client.getWeb3ClientVersion() 
 + "\n");
```

Comment: Does your private Ethereum blockchain node (located here *http://192.168.1.33:8501*) has enabled the json-rpc api? For example with geth: `--rpc --rpcport "8501" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "*"`

Comment: Yes, this is my geth command : `geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode full --port 30311 --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr 192.168.1.33 --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,admin,miner`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by disabling the firewall in my Blockchain node.